# Stuck at installing Ubuntu on Samsung Notebook 3

Tags: installation, 12.10, samsung

In my Samsung Notebook 3, when installing ubuntu 12.10  using usb stick it got stuck at the ubuntu logo.

I am sure my iso fine , first i tried ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386 it got stuck now i have tried ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64 it also failed.

Laptop configuration:

Model : NP305E5Z

CPU: AMD A4 1.96ghz

RAM: 4gb

### Please help me guys.....

Comment: If you type Esc to get to the screen of text under the logo, what errors do you see, or where is it stopped?

Comment: *Starting/Stopping enable remaining boot time encrypted block devices [OK]                                                              Cursor appears then stuck in the above process..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have tried Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amdx64 version after such a long time. I have installed it successfully. I don't know may be the kernel level update have fixed this issue.

After the installation I had faced heating problem, then I have managed to install the amd radeon graphics driver by using this guide, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD
Heating problem got fixed. Now I am using ubuntu without any hassle.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Could you install It? if not then at the first purple screen with a man & keyboard at the bottom hit Enter.. then choose language.. In the next screen hit F6 and choose 'nomodeset'... press escape & then install...

It will work and you have to install proprietary drivers later to get right resolution & all, but that is after your installation is complete...